# Facebook Company Page login when info is lost

Tags: facebook-pages, passwords

I'm the new GM for our company -- we have a Facebook page that is very outdated and no one knows how to access it by password or login - do we just abandon it and start over or do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook have a Help page entitled [How do I claim a Page that already exists for my business? Can I merge it with my business's official Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/168172433243582) If no one is managing the Page, you can request to claim it:

> 1. From the Page, click [image: Gear icon] below the Page's cover photo
> 2. Select **Is this your business?**.
> 3. Add and verify information about your business, like the address and
>      website, and click **Continue**.
> 4. Choose to verify your connection to the business by **Email** or
>      **Documentation**:
>
>    - **Email**: Choose this option if you have an email address associated    with your Facebook account that is officially issued to
>        you by your    business. Email addresses from generic providers like
>        Yahoo! or Gmail    will not be accepted. The email address should
>        correspond to your    business's name (ex: jane.doe@acmeproducts.com).
>    - **Documentation**: Choose this option to upload a scanned copy or photo    of an official document that shows your business's name and
>        address    (ex: phone bill, business license, business tax file or
>        articles of    incorporation).
> 5. Click **Submit**.